# How can I make this VB program recursive?

Tags: vb.net, function, recursion, methods, procedure

I need to use recursion in this program for a school project. The program checks if the number inputted is a real number (in this case defined by a number with a decimal with the characters 0-9 (e.g. 56.7). How would I make the function recursive?

Thanks :-)

```
Module Real_Numbers

    Sub Main()
        Dim number As String
        Dim check As Boolean
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number to check if it is a real number:")
        number = Console.ReadLine()
        check = CheckNumber(number)

        If check = True Then
            Console.WriteLine("The number is a real number")
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("The number is not a real number")
        End If
        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

    Function CheckNumber(ByVal number As String) As Boolean
        Dim current As Char
        For i As Integer = 0 To number.Length - 1
            current = number.Substring(i, 1)
            If current = "." Then
                ' Do nothing
            Else
                If IsNumeric(current) Then
                    ' Do nothing
                Else
                    Return False
                End If
            End If

        Next

        Return True

    End Function

End Module
```

Comment: I don't see why you need to make that recursive. Can you explain?

Comment: I think it's utter rubbish too, but the school is making us do it...

Comment: Isn't the  `IsNumeric()` function all you need? From what you are asking, it sounds like you need to determine if given some user input - determine if that input is a real number. The `IsNumeric()` function does just that - there is no need for recursion. Unless I am overlooking something, please let me know so I can try to help

Comment: Can you post exactly what you have been asked to do then as it sounds like you haven't followed the brief

Comment: @HardTacos `IsNumeric` alone won't work because it returns True for negative values, which are not real numbers

Comment: @MattWilko thank you for that reminder. Forgot it returned negatives.

Comment: NB: At most one decimal point. As it stands `12.34.56.78` is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Given that this is a homework assignment, I'm not going to write the code out for you.  But I will say this -- there are a couple of ways to set this up.  One straightforward way would be to pass the string (of the number) to CheckNumber and then check the first character -- if it's numeric, call CheckNumber again with the remainder of the string (everything minus what you just checked).  If it's not numeric, return false.  You'll need a special case to handle the very last character -- if it's numeric, then return true.  If you propagate the boolean response properly, your recursion should unwind itself at the end with the right answer.

Good luck!

Comment: You might have to cater for the decimal point (or better still decimal separator). Also, you don't want more than one of them.

Answer (score -1):

You should call the CheckNumber function from within itself, that is a recursion. Learn more about recursion [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion).